# How to attach i in 'for i in range(x)' to a label in python?

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter

I basically have this loop and I am trying to make it so that each of the labels in the GUI has a specific name so I can change them individually. I would like it to be cardlabelxy where x is the row and y is the column but I can'f figure out how to get it to work. Here is what I have:

```
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(6):
        (cardlabel+'i'+'j') = CardLabel(root)
        (cardlabel+'i'+'j').grid(row=i, column=j)
        (cardlabel+'i'+'j').configure(image=CardLabel.blank_image)
```

Can anyone help me with the syntax? the loop works fine if i just have

```
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(6):
        cardlabel = CardLabel(root)
        cardlabel.grid(row=i, column=j)
        cardlabel.configure(image=CardLabel.blank_image)
```

but then they are all called cardlabel which I don't want.

Comment: I dont know what a `CardLabel` is ... and I doubt anyone else does as well ... I assume root is some parent of whatever widget a `CardLabel` is

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't build dynamic variables; [keep your data out of your variables](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html). Build a *list or dictionary* instead.

With a dictionary, for example, it'd be:

```
card_labels = {}

for i in range(2):
    for j in range(6):
        label = CardLabel(root)
        label.grid(row=i, column=j)
        label.configure(image=CardLabel.blank_image)
        card_labels[i, j] = label
```

This stores the labels keyed on the `(i, j)` tuple in the `card_labels` dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using dictionary, like this:

```
cardlabels = {}

for i in range(2):
    for j in range(6):
        label = str(i)+'.'+str(j)
        cardlabels[label] = CardLabel(root)
        cardlabels[label].grid(row=i, column=j)
        cardlabels[label].configure(image=CardLabel.blank_image)
```

Now they will be labeled cardlabels['1.1'], cardlabels['1.2']..

Answer (score 0):

While I definitely recommend using either a dictionary or list solution, if you have your heart set on using variables, something like this should do the trick.

```
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(6):
        vars()['cardlabel%d%d' % (i,j)] = CardLabel(root)
        vars()['cardlabel%d%d' % (i,j)].grid(row=i, column=j)
        vars()['cardlabel%d%d' % (i,j)].configure(image=CardLabel.blank_image)
```